# "dll not found" error in Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am trying to build a Windows Phone 8 app using cocos2d-x in Visual Studio Express 2012. My Test project compiles without error but while trying to run in emulator the following message is shown.

```
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\programs\{2AC777CA-2D3B-41C8-98AC-B6ED1A4B0988}\Install\Test.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\NTDLL.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\WS2_32.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x828 has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
The program '[2084] Test.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
```

I have verified that the dll exists in "Windows\System32".

Has anyone faced this issue before. How do I solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What dll? You don't even know what dependency is missing here. Get depends.exe put your test.exe into it and see what dll is missing. What you see here is only what PDBs were loaded for external dependecies.

Comment: @Samuel I am new sorry. I am new to development using visual studio. the log said 'A dependent dll was not found' that is why i assumed it was related to the messages above. Could you explain how to figure out which dll is missing.

Comment: @glo - as Samuel mentioned, get depends.exe and see what the dependent DLL's are.  Then make sure that whatever DLL's your program is dependent on, that they are available to your program.  Get Dependency Walker here if you don't already have it: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error ('A dependent dll was not found') while running my application (cocos2d-x game) on windows10 (64-bit).

**Solution** -> I Uninstalled my app and then did a fresh installation from Visual Studio (2015). [Didn't need to re-install visual studio as mentioned in some other blogs.]

Possible Reason: There were some updates in windows10 by Microsoft lately, which may have altered some DLLs, and this could not be compatible with already installed application.